# Add components to a JSON string that has components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

So im having Some issues at making this component work.

The component itself its a sidebar that had routes and icons. Mostly material-ui components.
Firstly we had all our routes and and NavLinks in a constant file where it binds routes,components, names, icons, with their respective utility.
But now the same Json file comes trough the a fetch call and it gets stored in the store and then called by the SideBar compoenent but without the binded components!

On the begining it was something like this

```
import {iconName1, iconName2, iconName3, iconName4} from 'icons-lib-custom'

const routes = [
    {
        obj1: [
            {icon1: iconName1} 
            {route1: 'route'} //Ilustrative only, doesn't matter which route goes to
            ]
        obj2:[
            {icon2: iconName2}
            {route2: 'route'}
        ]
        obj3: [
            {icon3: iconName3}
            {route3: 'route'}
        ]
        obj4:[
            {icon4: iconName4}
            {route4: 'route'}
        ]
    }
]

export default function SideBar {

    return (

            <Sidebar
                routes={routes} //Worked well since it had the instance of the icons loaded when builded the constant
            />
    )
}
```

It changed to pulling the json already builded from the store, but without the intance of the icons itself.
we took away that constant routes and icons and made it trough the backend. Therefore it becomes something like this

```
export default function SideBar {
    const store = useSelector(state => state.session);
    return (

        <Sidebar
            routes={store.routes} // 'icons-lib-custom' doesnt have access to the icons inside the json store.routes
        />
    )
}
```

Has anyone know how to add the intance of those icons to the pulled Json from the store?
Maybe a lodash function? map throuhg the components and dinamically assing each compoenent? Whats the easy way i wonder?

Comment: [Choosing the Type as Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks but i think that implementation wouldn't work since i don't have a selector for the component

Comment: Sure it would, it has nothing to do with redux. You need to define the mapping of `iconX` to icon component and use where you need to render the icons for the routes.

Comment: How so? Mind explining a bit more? @DrewReese

Comment: Is it possible to get you to update your question with your `Sidebar` component that is receiving `store.routes`?

Comment: The Sidebar component is a material-ui component. It just needs the routes and the swiched routes

Comment: Hmm, so you need to define the icon components *before* they are passed to `SideBar` then, the same process still works, just occurs a little earlier.